# Autofac Lambda Expression Registeration

Tags: c#, autofac, ioc-container

I'm using lambda expression in order to register my component like this

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<EndPointServiceClient>().As<IEndPointService>();
builder.Register(imp => new EndPointImp(imp.Resolve<IEndPointService>())).As<IEndPointImp>();
builder.Register(log => new Login(LoginEnumType.EmployeeLogin, log.Resolve<IEndPointImp>()));
```

at the application start I resolve and instance of the login class which is a win form class

```
Login loginWindow = container.Resolve<Login>();
Application.Run(loginWindow);
```

but for some reason whenever I inspect the value of imp I find it set to null

```
public Login(LoginEnumType loginType, IEndPointImp imp)
{
    _loginType = loginType;
    _imp = imp;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

would anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong over here?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure why your instance is not working. I have used the code from your example and mocked this up with the code below, and it is indeed all working for me. I am resolved an instance of the Login class and imp is injected with an instance of IEndPointImp from the container.

Perhaps there is something from my example code below which you may have missed and might help you?

```
void Main()
{
    DependencyConfig.Configure();

    var loginWindow = DependencyConfig.Container.Resolve<Login>();
}

public class DependencyConfig
{
    public static IContainer Container { get; private set;}

    public static void Configure()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<EndPointServiceClient>().As<IEndPointService>();
        builder.Register(imp => new EndPointImp(imp.Resolve<IEndPointService>())).As<IEndPointImp>();
        builder.Register(log => new Login(LoginEnumType.EmployeeLogin, log.Resolve<IEndPointImp>()));

        Container = builder.Build();
    }
}

public enum LoginEnumType
{
    EmployeeLogin
}

public interface IEndPointService
{
}
public class EndPointServiceClient : IEndPointService
{
}

public interface IEndPointImp
{ 
}
public class EndPointImp : IEndPointImp
{
    private readonly IEndPointService _endPointService;

    public EndPointImp(IEndPointService endPointService)
    {
        _endPointService = endPointService;
    }
}

public class Login
{
    private readonly LoginEnumType _loginType;
    private readonly IEndPointImp _imp;

    public Login(LoginEnumType loginType, IEndPointImp imp)
    {
        _loginType = loginType;
        _imp = imp;
    }
}
```